# $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;

Tags: jquery, ajax, url, jquery-mobile, select

I've been struggling with this for several days now. I'm trying to get a Select menu to work as a navigation menu. But when I click on the buttons nothing happens. Thanks to @Enrico, I think I have the changePage code correct. I also discovered that Ajax needed to be turned off on the links. I've gone a bit overboard with trying to get Ajax disabled. Here's my code in the head:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile.structure-1.2.0.min.css" />
<base href="http://kickfitness.com/" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script language="text/javascript">
/* VERY IMPORTANT this is before loading jquery.mobile JS */
$( document ).on( "mobileinit", function() {
    // Make your jQuery Mobile framework configuration changes here!
    $.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true;
            $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
            });
 $(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){
        $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
        });
</script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.js"></script>

<script language="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $("#select-choice-1").change(function() {
        $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
        $.mobile.changePage($(this).val());
    });        
});
</script>
```

Here is my menu:

```
<div id="MobileWrapper" data-role="fieldcontain">
<select name="select-choice-1" id="select-choice-1" data-theme="a" data-form="ui-btn-up-a"data-native-menu="false" data-mini="false"><!-- data-native-menu="false" -->
<option data-placeholder="true">Navigation</option><!-- data=placeholder makes this not show up in the pop up-->
<option value="http://kickfitness.com/index.php">Home</option>
<option value="/services/index.php">Services</option>
<option value="trainers/index.php">Trainers</option>
<option value="/locations/index.php">Locations</option>
<option value="/calendar/index.php">Calendar</option>
<option value="/contactus/index.php">Contact Us</option>
</select>
</div><!--END MobileWrapper DIV-->
```

Here is a URL to the page. It is done with responsive CSS so you can see the mobile nav by making your browser window really small.
    http://kickfitness.com/services/index2.php

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The difference in the URL links in the nav was for testing variations. Hoping one of them would work.

Comment: It "works" at least on chrome and opera, page changes, there are some glitches here and there (like... the select is not enhanced on /services/index2.php but it is enhanced on index.php, some pages does not show the select, etc). You should describe your problem a little better...

Comment: It only works because I had to use a older version of jQuery.

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile.structure-1.1.1.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.js"></script>

Comment: <script type='text/javascript'>
 var urlmenu = document.getElementById( 'select-choice-1' );
 urlmenu.onchange = function() {
      window.open(this.options[ this.selectedIndex ].value,'_self');
 };
</script>

Answer (score 0):

You don't need all the $.mobile.ajaxEnabled settings, just call changePage with option "reloadPage"  equal to true:

```
$(function() {
    $("#select-choice-1").change(function() {
        $.mobile.changePage($(this).val(), { reloadPage: true } );
    });        
});
```

Comment: Seems closer, but still not working. I have placed your code into my page. It seems to go to the last page visited instead of the intended page. That occurs with and without the ajaxeEnabled stuff and base href stuff. Any other thoughts? Client is hot to get the site live. I have a version working, but without all this mobile jQuery. Just not as nice: http://www.kickfitness.com/services/index.php